# Parent View height is ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have custom `LinearLayout`, which is parent of my child views. I'm adding child views into this parent `View` using `parent.addView()` by inflating child layout. This `LinearLayout` is wrapped in `ScrollView`, so I can scroll child views if there is more there. Problem is that `LinearLayout` height is ignored if I add child views there (it stretched to full screen height for some reason). This behaviour is completely destroying need of `ScrollView`. Any reason why is it happening? I need some `maxHeight` parameter for this to work. It should stretch only to max of 200dp.

Layout:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/resultList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_medium"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use android:fillViewport="true" in your recyclerView & Chnage scrollView height to match_parent / 0dp. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behaviour by using a root of a ConstraintLayout with a child of a ScrollView with height to wrap_content and a maximum height to 200dp using the property  **app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"** and the ScrollView child will be the LinearLayout with layout_height to wrap_content.

Below is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/resultList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the result after adding 3 child Views of 50dp height with different colours to LinearLayout with a total height smaller than 200dp will be like below (No Scroll required):

[image: three_scrolling_views]

And the result after adding 9 child Views of 50dp height with different colours to LinearLayout with total height greater than 200dp will be like below (Scroll is required) (ScrollView has its max height to 200dp):

[image: nine_scrolling_views]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what the goal of your layout is. It seems to me that *ScrollView* is making some assumption about the height of its child being unbounded (and it can have only one child.) If you want the *LinearLayout* to have a specific height, set that height on the *ScrollView* itself.